# Graphite Percentage Calculation with groupby/Wildcards for alerting Target Function

Tags: graphite, seyren

I am trying to create a seyren alert for my page render metric stored in graphite.

My render stats are collected by ststsD and stored in graphite. The structure is following:

```
stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.<country>.<placement_id>.<page_version>.count
```

e.g.

```
stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.123456.v1_1_03.count
stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.123456.v1_1_09.count

stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.654321.v2_1_05.count
stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.654321.v2_1_07.count

stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.UK.123456.v1_1_09.count
...
...
```

I want to create a seyren alert with graphite function whenever the current render count for ANY PLACEMENT ANY VERSION (e.g. group by placement_id, page_version) falls below certain % of its (for that placement's and version's) previous day average.

I did search graphite functions but it's bit confusing probably because I don't have background in time-series data processing. Will truly appreciate any help. I tried with many combinations including the following, but not able to get it correct...

```
asPercent(sumSeriesWithWildCards(movingAverage(scaleToSeconds(
 stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.*.*.count, 1),'10min'), 6), 
sumSeriesWithWildCards(movingAverage(scaleToSeconds(timeShift(
 stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.*.*.count, '1d'), 1), '10min'), 6))
```

Please note, I want to create only one alert (hence using WildCard function like sumSeriesWithWildCards) which should serve the purpose, not multiple alerts for individual placements and versions and we keep on adding these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, any suggestion on this, will really appreciate.

Comment: After doing many search I came up with the following formula, which seems to be close but still the numbers does not look right, will appreciate if you can comment what's is missing here:

    asPercent(
     groupByNode(
      movingAverage(
    
   scaleToSeconds(stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.*.*.count, 1),
      '2hour'),
     5, 'averageSeries'),
     groupByNode(
      movingAverage(
       scaleToSeconds(
        timeShift(stats.counters.renderCompleted.display.US.*.*.count, '1d'),
       1),
      '2hour'),
     5, 'averageSeries')
    )